MongoDB Atlas CLI: atlas command not found
I am trying to use MonngoDB Atlas CLI. I have installed Atlas in a Ubuntu virtual environment following  the official documentation. Apparently everything works. However, if I close and reopen the virtual environment and I type atlas I get: Command 'atlas' not found.
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for your help!

In a new shell/terminal you need to activate the virtual environment again.

Why did you install it in a Ubuntu virtual environment? It's a simple exe, why do you not run it directly at your computer?

I am running it on a Django app.
